# Svelte transitions and animations on page load

Tags: svelte, svelte-transition

I am currently working on a website using Svelte and Sapper. I'm using Svelte transitions to animate some of the page elements. Whenever I change to a new page route, the transitions animate correctly. But when I load the page for the first time, they do not animate.

How does Svelte handle animations on page load? Do I need to use onMount() to get them to work properly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because Sapper server-renders pages, `intro: true` would result in an awkward flash of visible content becoming invisible then transitioning back in.

To avoid that, you need to prevent content being server-rendered in the first place. The easiest way to do that is indeed to use `onMount`:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let ready = false;
  onMount(() => ready = true);
</script>

<div class="always-visible">
  {#if ready}
    <div class="visible-on-mount">...</div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: @FractalHQ created a nice [component](https://fractils.vercel.app/#OnMount) for this

Comment: I think now you can use the `global` modifier for transitions