# Svelte transition seems to finish too soon

Tags: html, css, svelte, svelte-transition

I'm trying to build a simple transition in Svelte where I have cards that animate in on page load. I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396362/svelte-transitions-and-animations-on-page-load) to get it to fire correctly `onMount`, so that has been ok. However, the transition itself seems to "jump" to the end too quickly, and skips the last few frames.

[GIF of problem running on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UERy3.gif).

Oddly enough, when I copy and paste the same code into the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a34e92c0ae14295828cc9899a4ec2a1?version=3.46.3), the visual bug seems to be fixed. I've even downloaded the REPL and run locally, and the bug still appears.

Here is the code.

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    const contents = [
        {
            id: 1,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
        },
    ];

    let ready = false;
    onMount(() => (ready = true));
</script>

<main>
    <div class="topBar" />
    <div class="container">
        {#if ready}
            {#each contents as content, i}
                <div
                    class="transCard"
                    transition:fly={{ y: 80, duration: 1000, delay: i * 200 }}
                />
            {/each}
        {/if}
    </div>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        background: white;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 16px;
        padding: 16px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .topBar {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 80px;
        background: black;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9;
    }

    .transCard {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background: gray;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: main is the size of the viewport, so I was expecting a position fixed or absolute and a left & top of 0. I think the jump might be caused by the containers, the scroll posiiton was also unexpected in the gif, don't know what would cause that behavior.

Comment: Mmm, tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself! Not sure why it fixed it, but for me changing `transition` to just `in` seems to have cured the visual bug.